# Translation Operator for Position on Momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators

Consider the translation operator
$$\hat T=\exp[-ic\hat p/\hbar], $$
which acts on the position operator in the following way:
$$\hat T^\dagger \hat q\hat T = \hat q+c.$$
If I take $\hat T ^\dagger \hat p \hat T $, will this just spit back p?  I tried doing out the math explicitly and found that the commutator $[\hat p,\hat T]=[\hat p,e^{\hat p}]=0$ which means that it does not actually translate it.

My confusion is if this will spit back p, or if this quantity should be evaluated to be 0.

Comment: In the definition of $\hat{T}$, don't you have $c$ instead of $x$?

Comment: @Slaviks I think you are correct. I already changed that (and I used that definition in my answer), but my change awaits confirmation. Cheers, ZZ

Comment: @Slaviks Nothing changed. Apparently they didn't accept this change. But it should be there, I'll try again.

Comment: @ZoltanZimboras a lot of reviewers prefer that changes like that be suggested in a comment, and that you wait for the OP to make the edit. But it does depend on who reviews the edit.

Comment: @DavidZ Thanks for letting me know. Next time I mention it in the comment, and wait for the OP to edit it.

Comment: The question looks fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $[\hat{p},\hat{T}]=0$ and $\hat{T}$ is unitary ($\hat{T}\hat{T}^{\dagger}=\hat{T}^{\dagger}\hat{T}= \mathbf{1}$) we have that $\hat{T}^{\dagger} \hat{p} \hat{T}= \hat{T}^{\dagger}\hat{T}\hat{p}=\hat{p}$.

*Edit after a question in the comments*:

$[\hat{T}, \hat{p}]=0$ holds. For simplicity let us use the $\hbar=1$ units. We know that $\hat{T}=\exp(-ic\hat{p})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \tfrac{(-ic)^n}{n!}\hat{p}^n$, as $\hat{p}$ commutes term by term with this expression (since $[\hat{p}^n,\hat{p}]=0$) it follows that $[\hat{T},\hat{p}]=0$.

Comment: Am I correct that [p,T]=0?

Comment: Yes, let $\hbar=1$. Since $\hat{T}=\exp(-ic\hat{p})=\sum_n (-ic\hat{p})^n/n!$, we have that $\hat{p}$ commutes with all terms (as $[\hat{p}^n,\hat{p}]=0$ holds, of course). Hence $[\hat{T}, \hat{p}]=0$.

Comment: This follows from the (strong version of the) B-C-H formula. You assert that your equality takes place on a dense everywhere invariant subspace of the Hilbert space for which an arbitrary function of the momentum operator will be defined through its Taylor expansion.

Comment: @yankeefan11 I hope this explains it. Btw, in the question you defined $T$ a bit ambiguously. I will exchange there $x$ with $c$ in the definition to make it compatible with the formula below (and not confuse anybody with the fact that $x$ is not an operator there). I hope these changes are okay with you.

Comment: Kindof a followup?  If I take $T^\dagger qp T$ would that just go to (q+c)p?

Comment: @yankeefan11 Exactly! $T^{\dagger}qpT=T^{\dagger}qTp=(q+c)p$.